# How can I log which interface a BIND query is received on?

Tags: logging, bind

I'm in the process of changing the IP address of my nameserver and I want a way to tell how many queries I am still receiving on the old IP address to track how well the change is being picked up.

Is this something I can do in BIND9 logging or would I have to go outside it to something like tcpdump to track this? I want to still process queries on multiple IPs but I want some sign of the relative quantity of queries between the 2 IPs.

Comment: What operating system is it on?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hack: for each IP, use identical `named.conf` config files except for different `listen-on` directives and a `logging` clause for for the old IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I fear Bind can not do it. There is no print-interface available. See the documentation: http://www.bind9.net/manual/bind/9.3.2/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2553006

Maybe Iptables helps to do that. There is a ULOG target for user space logging of packets and a corresponding ulogd. See here: http://www.netfilter.org/projects/ulogd/